# Как выбрать из MySQL количество сгруппированных записей

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, называется учебный план.

```
Специальность, семестр, предмет, тип аттестации
Программист, 1, История, зачет
Программист, 1, Химия, зачет
Программист, 2, Химия, экзамен
Программист, 2, История, зачет
Программист, 3, Физика, зачет
Программист, 3, История, экзамен
```

Как выбрать данные, сгруппировав по ПРЕДМЕТАМ, так чтобы, было 2 столбца, зачет, экзамен. а значения - семестры, в которых эти зачеты или экзамены, если предмет есть в двух семестрах, то перечислить семестры через запятую

**Пример**

```
           Экзамен    Зачет
История      3         1,2
Химия        2          1
Физика                  3
```

Comment: Предложите свой вариант запроса, а мы уже подскажем/подправим/переделаем!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [ответ на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql), вот [ссылка на оф. документацию по функции](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)